Angular google versus google maps api
I want to know if I use this library angular/google-maps if I can do all things that tha api of google maps can do.
I don't know which option is better or if I use the module for angular of google maps maybe I will lose some options.
I don't know which one to decide, I have installed the angular/google-maps @16.3.1 version but I don't know if it will have the same potential as using directly integrating the Google Maps API into my Angular project.
I tried to install the api of google maps angular/google-maps in my angular project but I don't know which is the best option.
